# How to edit a plist file by key type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, plist

I want to add into my plist file present in "prefPlist" variable some key with its relative type.

The example content must be:

```
<dict>
    <key>App Version</key>
    <string>Beta 1</string>
    <key>Configuration Type</key>
    <integer>7</integer>
    <key>Creation Date</key>
    <date>27 04 2013, 03:00</date>
    <key>Want some milk?</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The first key must have the string type, the second the integer type, the third the date time type and the fourth a boolean value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>prefList</key>
<array>
  <string>string</string>
  <string>integer</string>
  <string>date</string>
  <string>boolean</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This isn't what I mean. Sorry, I haven't explained well.

I want to write, in the dictionary, the key whit its relative type.

Answer (score 0):

Matteo:

You should be able to read the NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary messages supported [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In the meantime, it seems as though you want to use, as an example:

```
NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName ofType:@"plist"];
myDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:source] mutableCopy];
```

This of course assumes that the plist is in your bundle. Use FileManager to your sandbox documents or elsewhere to get the right location before loading with dictionary.

Frank